# Get the variables out of the while loop

Tags: php, html, css

I would understand if there is a way to store the variables out of the while loop.
For example, I have a slide show that shows the images for each category present and a button to see the images gallery related to the category. The button, for graphical issues, should stay out of the CSS class that contains the while.

This is the current code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner"> <!-- start carousel -->
  $macrocat = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE cat_parent_id = 0";      
   $result = dbQuery($macrocat);
      while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
             extract($row);
        echo $cat_name;
        echo $cat_description;
 }
</div> <!-- end carousel -->
```

and the class out of the while where I have to get cat_id:

```
<div class="social-caption">
 <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="categorie.php?id=<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">Gallery</a>
</div>
```

How can I fix the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: So should `.social-caption` be created for each row found? Why not just save each row into a new array in the while and re-loop the data for the buttons?

Comment: maybe, just maybe you should share what you are doing inside of `extract()`?  You use `$cat_name, $cat_description, $cat_id` in your code but do not assign them anywhere probably MAGIC, heh? Or inside that function maybe? :D

Comment: SmokeyPHP, Maybe the way you say is correct, but how can i use arrays in this case?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Not sure what you're trying to get at, but `extract()` is a core PHP function and has been for a long time. It converts array elements into variables.

Comment: @user2741100 Above the while initiate `$results=array()`, then inside the loop add `$results[]=$row;` - you can then do a foreach over `$results` to generate the buttons with `foreach($results as $row)`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP thanks for pointing that out learned something again :)

Comment: First time I see *extract()* function. I have learned something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the categories first:

```
<div class="carousel-inner"> <!-- start carousel -->
  $macrocat = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE cat_parent_id = 0";   
  $cats = array[];   
   $result = dbQuery($macrocat);
      while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
             extract($row);
        echo $cat_name;
        echo $cat_description;
        $cats[] = $cat_id;
 }
</div> <!-- end carousel -->
```

Then later you can use them:

```
foreach($cats as $cat)
  {
  echo "<div>".$cat."</div>";
  }
```

Comment: Thx for spotting that, lame_up_ducky

Comment: @Jelle Ferwerda: It works thanks, but i can't use it outside <div class="carousel-inner"> 'cause prints all the buttons for all categories... I do not know if there may be solutions out of that class :-(

Comment: Hi, that makes sense.. As you are echoing all of them I think..:

        echo $cat_name;
        echo $cat_description;

In your select I think you just want to show:  
SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE cat_id = $SomeSelectedCategory

And perhaps use a different query to get all the categories.

Comment: The problem is that it is a carousel and its class is controlled by jquery. Whenever I scroll, the carousel is given $cat_id correctly, but out of that class, the foreach(), gives me all $cat_id immediately ... I suppose I have to find another way, holding the button inside that class, and then maybe with a CSS solution.